# Jasny bootstrap with Bootswatch themes not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, themes

I am trying to use [vertical navbar](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu/) of Jasny bootstrap along with Boootswatch custom themes.
The problem I am facing is that the navbar color is hardcoded in the Jasny booostrap and no matter what theme I use, the navabar color remains the same.

I tried to chnage the colors manually using the Yeti Theme, nut I am not able to achive the correct representation of the menu.

```
.navmenu-inverse,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-offcanvas {
    background-color: #008cba;
    border-color: #006687;
}

    .navmenu-inverse .navmenu-brand,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-offcanvas .navmenu-brand {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .navmenu-inverse .navmenu-brand:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-offcanvas .navmenu-brand:hover,
    .navmenu-inverse .navmenu-brand:focus,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-offcanvas .navmenu-brand:focus {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
```

Can anyone help me to correct it using [Yeti theme](http://bootswatch.com/yeti/)?

Also, Is there any easy way to make it compatible with every theme included in [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/)??

Thank you in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors are **not** hard coded, they are in fact variables in Less (and Sass).

The easiest way is to use [the customizer](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/customize/#less-variables) to set the colors of the navmenu.

If you want to add Jasny Bootstrap to all of Bootswatch themes

- Fork the [bootswatch repository](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch).
- Install Jasny Bootstrap with bower: `bower install -S jasny-bootstrap`.
- Add `@import "../bower_components/jasny-bootstrap/less/jasny-bootstrap.less";` to [global/build.less](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/blob/gh-pages/global/build.less).
- Add customized [Jasny Bootstrap variables](https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less) to the [Yeti theme variables.less](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/blob/gh-pages/yeti/variables.less). Repeat this for each theme.
- Run `grunt`.

Comment: I am new to less and grunt.. Is there a more simpler way? And how do i set the colors in the customizer?

Comment: The simpeler way is the customizer. Scroll to 'Less variables' > 'Navmenu'. There you see fields like `@navmenu-default-color` with hex codes for each color. Change those, scroll down and press 'Customize and download'.

Comment: I did not understand the 4th point? Can you explain in detail? Or Can you do it for me?

Comment: @writeToBhuwan copy/paste